# Does Page verification require downtime?

Tags: sql-server, sp-blitz

So I used sp_blitz and came across  a suggestion to change verification to checksum. What I want to know is, would this step require any downtime?

Answer (score 3):

Nope, no downtime for this change at all.

Here's the explanation of what/when things happen:

> Keep in mind that just changing the setting to CHECKSUM does not
>   instantly add CHECKSUMs to your existing data pages in the database.
>   In order for this to happen, you have to read each page into memory,
>   make some sort of change and then write it back out to the storage
>   subsystem. This can happen from normal INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE activity
>   over time, or from rebuilding your indexes.

Source: http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/glenn/setting-your-page-verify-database-option-to-checksum/